# Concatenating strings in bash overwrites them

Tags: bash

I'm parsing query results from a mysql command (with the --table parameter)

```
local records=`echo "${query}" | $MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS --table`
```

The query is run successfully, and I receive good data.

Then I iterate over this data:

```
for data in $records ;
do
    test+=$data
done
```

The code is more extensive, but this is basically it.
Bash sees every space as a separator though, and that's a problem for text fields.

So I just concatenate them. But when I feed bash this data:

```
*URL*
host:
test.url.com
pass:
anothertest

http://www.test.com
```

It concatenates it to something like:

```
pass:test.url.com.com
```

As if it's not concatenating, but overwriting.
Is this maybe some carriage return problem?

Comment: It sounds like you may be getting carriage returns embedded in the string somehow, but I can't tell where from what you posted. Try printing your various strings with e.g. `printf "test=%q\n" "$test"` -- bash's %q format will print a quoted-format string, which makes it much easier to discern things like carriage returns. Try printing `"$data"` each time through the loop, then printing `"$test"` at the end and see how they look.

Comment: I had the same problem and for me it was the carriage return of windows. After changing it to Linux ending, it worked.

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue with the stderr output retrieved from the `curl` command. I found that the output contains carriage return that needs to be removed. For the example above this could be done using the `tr` tool:

```
for data in $records ;
do
    data=$(echo "$data" | tr -d '\r')
    test+="$data"
done
```

Answer (score 9):

Check that you use Unix line endings. Using Windows line endings caused the same behavior for me, overwriting strings.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using Bash 3 or later.  The `+=` operator in Bash can be used to manipulate an Array.  It will use the current value of the `IFS` variable to split the tokens and add the value to the array.

Try:
`test="$test $data"` to concatenate the data

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at setting the [IFS variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSH) if you are seeing issues with line separators.

Something like

```
IFS="\n"
```

Also be careful with `+=` as it can fall back to array manipulation depending on the version of BASH.